# gethostbyname failure and network timeouts in jail

Tags: freebsd, jail

I have a FreeBSD DigitalOcean droplet in which I followed [this guide](https://www.kirkg.us/posts/how-to-configure-a-freebsd-jail-on-a-digital-ocean-droplet/) **exactly** for setting up a jail. The problem is I cannot get reliable network connectivity inside the jail. Doing `curl https://www.google.com/` I get a ~1 minute delay when trying to connect to the server:

[image: curl failure]

After the second asterisk the connection was established very, very quickly. With `ping` I get 100% packet loss, and occasionally I cannot resolve hostnames. It won't work during one command, but then it will after a short delay before I try the next.

I tried `ssh -T git@github.com` to see if SSH works reliably and I seem to be able to always get a connection (when hostname lookup works).

I only have these issues in the jail, not on the host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies somewhere in DigitalOcean's networking. Some others on Twitter reported the same issue and migrating to AWS with the *same exact* setup works 100% fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't `ping` from a jail unless you allow it specifically. This is so by default because it triggers security problems. You can allow a jail to `ping`, but you should only do this if you really don't have any other solution. More about it [there](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/freebsd-jail-allow-ping-tracerouter-commands/).

Now, instead of using `ping`, you could use `host` to check if the network connection is fine:

```
# host google.com
```

As for the `curl` question: in pf.conf, you should enable tcp and udp in and out for port http (and maybe https too, if you need it) but also enable udp for port dns. Something like:

```
pass in on $ext_if proto { tcp, udp } from any to $ext_if port $webports
pass out on $ext_if proto { tcp, udp } from $ext_if to any port $webports 

pass out on $ext_if proto udp from $ext_if to any port $dns_port
```

Where you should have defined webports and dns_port to fit your needs.

Also, when you followed the guide, you made a copy of your hosts' /etc/resolv.conf. Maybe check what's in it, depending on your hosts' configuration in some cases it may not work in jails.

PS: as of the gethostbyname failure, it's written in your title but not mentionned in your post. This could relate to /etc/hosts configuration, but can't say more.

Comment: Sorry, I should have followed up with this post. It's apparently a networking issue with DigitalOcean. Some others on Twitter reported the same issue. I used the same exact setup on AWS and everything worked 100% fine.